# iOS version/device statistics - where can I find?

Tags: iphone, ios

Since I am developing iOS apps I'm trying to find stats on how many iOS devices there are out there. Preferably broken down into versions: Iphone 3G, Iphone 3Gs, Iphone 4 etc.

Also I'd like to know the stats on different iOS versions.

After an hour of googling I found out that it is not the easiest thing to find. Anyone got some nice bookmarked links to share?

Comment: I wish there was a place that published this periodically. Flurry or Google Analytics or something. Right now I trust that 4.0 adoption is very very high, but six months from now, knowing 5.0 penetration would be very good when designing new apps.

Comment: Yes I agree. I also wish that Apple would be a little more transparent when it comes to stats and figures :)

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/08/ios-versions-in-the-wild/) is what you're looking for. A quick summary:

> 4.0 and above = 98.2%
>
> less than 4.0 = 1.8 %
>
> 52.23% have 4.3.3
>
> 14.37% have 4.3.4
>
> 13.57% have 4.2.1

Now this article is from August 3rd of 2011, so it's a bit old, but the data is new enough to be relevant.

Also, 30 seconds of Googling got this :P

Comment: Thanks, but those numbers come from users that have installed two specific apps, that I've actually never heard of. That doesn't tell me much. I'm looking for stats that covers all users. If that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

It's specific to his app (Instapaper) but Marco Arment publishes a fairly complete breakdown of device and version stats for his users:

http://www.marco.org/2011/08/13/instapaper-ios-device-and-version-stats-update

Comment: Thanks, but like I told BlackJack, I don't think those numbers are relevant for me. Since they come from two specific apps, which has kind of the opposite target audience than my app.

Comment: Those numbers are relavant, as those are closer to the numbers of users that actually download or buy apps.  The raw numbers in the field (including people with old devices who rarely or never download apps) are probably even farther from your actual potential target audience numbers.